# Where to find OnInitialUpdate in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I am following [this](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/game_programming/same_game_part1_p3.html) turorial where it says to find OnInitialUpdate in SameGameView.h, I can not find this in Visual Studio 2010 professional.

Answer (score 0):

This is a virtual function, you need to rewrite it, using app-wizard

see here
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc7fw3a0(v=vs.100).aspx